# Ag Grid Module binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

Can't bind to `modules` since it isn't a known property of `ag-grid-angular`

[image]

```html
<ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      id="myGrid"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [modules]="modules"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [masterDetail]="true"
      [detailCellRendererParams]="detailCellRendererParams"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: import { GridOptions, Module, AllModules } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules'; 
                                                                                                                                
Written TS Code :   public modules: Module[] = AllModules;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Resolve the issue for "Can not found Module[]"=> Use any[] array
eg. public modules:any[] = AllCommunityModules;